# Magento & Google eCommerce Analytics

Tags: magento-1.7, google-analytics

Does Magento 1.8.0.0 CE already include the Google eCommerce tracking code?

If not, how would one implement the Google eCommerce tracking code specifically for Magento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does. There is a Google Analytics module. To activate, insert your GA UA-code into the `System > Configuration > Google API` administration area:

[image]

By default this is the **GA Async version - not the new universal analytics code**. After enabling and input of your UA you should then see it show up in your page source.

Events like ecommerce conversion are already built in, and funnels for checkout will populate. It's a fairly fully-featured GA ecommerce build out-of-the-box.

Comment: Yes I have done this already but my eCommerce data was not showing up. I found out that this is probably because eCommerce was not enabled on the google analytics settings page.

Comment: Are there plans to update the GA script to the universal code?

Comment: Have a look at this topic http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63442/15175