# Magento Enhanced Ecommerce Google Analytics Implementation

Tags: magento-1.8, google-analytics

How do i implement enhanced ecommerce google analytics on magento?

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look with your favorite search engine and Magento connect, there is even a free alternative on my first search.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-1.html

Comment: Or http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-universal-analytics-1.html

Comment: tried both the modules., first one is full of bugs and broken our site as well and second one doesn't fully support enhanced ecommerce features

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate if will cost you some bucks. 
But used this extension several times and was for me worth any penny. implementation in seconds and it works just great

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-universal-analytics.html

Hope this answers your question. 
Cheers.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps.

Comment: can anyone share complete example of enhanced ecommerce implementation and i don't want to buy any extension for my magento site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code snippets how the enhanced ecommerce lifecycle of a single product can be measured from initial impression to transaction using the enhanced ecommerce plug-in can be found using the following link provide by Google -:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#example

I think it will be a good starting point if you are a good developer, has plenty of time in hand and not willing to spend money otherwise you could buy the following extension which does everything as described in the above link and only extension I found doesn't give you performance degradation on your website -:

https://www.scommerce-mage.co.uk/magento-google-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking.html

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced Ecommerce Google Analytics is a Free Magento Extension which allows you to use the newly launched feature of Google Analytics – Enhanced Ecommerce.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-1.html